# Petrel 2012 could not find license server

Tags: ocean, petrel

I am using windows8 and getting following errors:

First I tried to to install Schlumberger licensing 2012 but I am getting a runtime error.

Then I installed schlumberger licensing 2010. But petrel 2012  could not able to find locahost license server inspite of the fact that petrel 2011 is working  properly.

Are these errors are related to windows 8??. I read somewhere that Petrel is not compatible with windows 8??

Comment: Petrel 2012 does not officially support windows 8. Do you get the same errors on other operating systems? What error message do you get?

Comment: I didn't used in other operationg system.. I started using petrel 2011 and it worked fine

Comment: Although Petrel might work fine on Windows 8, we do not guarantee it will as we do not fully supporte this OS yet (as of today)